# Where can I check the SP I used in mysql

Tags: mysql

all
Someone created xxx.mysql (SP) in mysql. However when I try to CALL it, the error message says, that SP does not exist. Can anyone tell me where I can check if this SP really does not exist in the database? Can I use phpmyadmin to check it?

Many thanks in advand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all the stored procedures in a MySQL database using this SQL:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_TYPE, ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA='dbname';
```

(replace dbname with the name of your database)

You can find more information and tips on stored procedures here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-stored-procs.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html